# How to force a user to choose a <select> option with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to work the answer out to this for hours and it's driving me insane!

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and bootstrap-min.js.

Here is my code:

```
<select id="assettype" name="assettype" class="input-medium required">
   <option>-- Please select --</option>
   <option value="1">Printer</option>
   <option value="2">Scanner</option>
</select>
```

If a user leaves the form as the '-- Please select --' option then I want an error to prevent the user from submitting the form i.e. forcing them to make a selection.

Any help would be massively appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thin the both answers works if you replace your 1st option by `<option value="">-- Please select --</option>`. Otherwise, the value will be `-- Please select --`

Comment: does it work to simply add `required="required"` as an attribute on your `select` tag?

Comment: @Plato required works only for html5 navigator

Comment: @Asenar you're right (1st comment).  however [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) is here to rescue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('#formId').submit(function (e) {
    if ($('#assettype').val() == '') {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop form submission
}
});
```

---

or

Using [jQuery Validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```
$.validator.addMethod('notNone', function (value, element) {
    return (value != '');
}, 'Please select an option');
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        assettype: {
            required: true,
            notNone: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that most of the answers would work but this is the one that I've implemented. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

This seems you need a simple *validation before submitting* like

```
$('#formId').submit(function () {
 if ($('#assettype').val() != '')) {  //Check the value of select
    return true; //allow to submit the form
 }
 else {       
    alert("Please select an option");
    return false;  //Prevent form being submitted
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="my_form" method="POST" action="" >
<select id="assettype" name="assettype" class="input-medium required">
  <option value="0" >-- Please select --</option>
  <option value="1">Printer</option>
  <option value="2">Scanner</option>
</select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#my_form").submit(
    var check_value = $("#assettype").val();
    if (check_value == 0)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      // prevent the user he has to choose something
      // by an alert for example, or background change of the element
      $("#assettype").css("background-color", "red");
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      // and restore it if it's ok
      $("#assettype").css("background-color", "inherit");
    }
    return true;
  });
</script>
```